# A single user receives "The required field data type is not supported" error in PowerApps form

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

In our SharePoint Online site, we have a list which has a customized PowerApps form.  This works perfectly fine for all users, except one.  This one person gets the following error when they attempt to Add new items to the list:

> The requested operation is invalid.  Server Response: The required
>   field "Field Name" data type is not supported.

The user cannot select from choice fields (since they are all blank), and is unable to submit the form since they are required fields.

The user appears to have the required edit permissions in order to add items to this list.  They also appear to be able to use other PowerApps forms attached to different lists in the same site.  It just seems to be a problem for this one user, for this one list.

Thanks in advance for any advice or suggestions on where to look from here...

Comment: Looks like you are using lookup columns in power apps, ensure that the particular user has access to the "looked up" list.

Comment: Thank you, yes - there was one lookup column in the list, and the user indeed did not have permission on the other referenced list.  After correcting permissions, the user could now use the PowerApps form without error.

Comment: You are welcome :) , you can accept it as answer which will remove this question from the `Unanswered ` section :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, the column is of type lookup.

So, you need to provide access to the user of the "looked up" list.

Once the user has access, they will be able to view the choices in the dropdown.